# Send POST request with a body using scala and play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I`m trying to send post request to external url using play framework and scala. I want to add some parameters to the body also.
I want to send a post request to "http://www.posonlinedemo.tk" with parameters **TransactionNo='T10000'** and **reqtype='T'**
how could i do it?

here is my Action

```
def test(para:String) = Action {
      val url: Option[String] = Some("http://www.posonlinedemo.tk")

         url match {
             case Some(url) => Redirect(url)
             case None => NotFound("This URL leads nowhere. :(")
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Play WS API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS).

As you can see in the documentation, it is that simple:

```
ws
  .url(url)
  .post(Map(
    "TransactionNo" -> Seq("T10000"), 
    "reqtype" -> Seq("T")))
```

Don't forget to add `ws` to your library dependencies.

Comment: ws is not supporting. I have followed your link also. few compile errors came with that.
** object HttpEntity is not a member of package play.api.http**
** object stream is not a member of package akka **

Comment: Which version of Play! are you using? The snipped of code I have posted compiles with Play! 2.4 and Play! 2.5 is you correctly add ws to your library dependencies and you inject it or import it in the file where it is used.

Comment: I`m using version 2.4.6

Comment: So it works, I just tested it to be sure. The errors you get are not from this snippet of code. You should accept the answer.